# Playgrounds "Collect, Toggle, Repeat" in 10 basic commands or less?

Tags: swift, ipad

[iPad Playgrounds app](https://www.apple.com/swift/playgrounds/), very early challenge: you're learning programming, you don't know anything about variables, loops, etc. The only keyword you know is `func`. The game advices you to build your own function for the first time.

[image: challenge start]

Basically, you're only going to use what's on screen: `collectGem()`, `moveForward()`, `name()`, `toggleSwitch()`, `turnLeft()`, `turnRight()`. You won't fall accidentally (so extra moves are acceptable), and the goal is to collect 4 gems and toggle 4 switches.

My first attempt was:

[image: challenge end]

Puzzle is solved, but tells me:

> *but you used 11 commands! Try defining your own function [...] You won't need to use as many commands*

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to use less commands with just the `func` keyword. Is it possible? ([note that I already figured out that using loops is cheating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEwe9.jpg))

Also, are there places to discuss about Playgrounds puzzles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**11 calls is enough indeed!**

*(but function names and structure of the code should be of a certain style)*

If you're to take *Thomas L Holaday's* answer and to rename the functions (for example instead of `bounce()` you'd put `clear()`), the solution no longer validates! Same with the name of the `b()` function!

After tinkering with the code and function names I found it is possible to code it with 11 calls, which is almost the same as original, and pass validation!

```
func bounce() {
  moveForward()
  collectGem()
  moveForward()
  toggleSwitch()
  moveForward()
  moveForward()
  turnLeft()
}

func b() {
  bounce()
  bounce()
}

b()
b()
```

[Here is the screen of my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rBH4.jpg)

It seems that the problem here is not with the solutions (which are correct!) but with the validator incorrect way of checking for the naming of the functions and the structure of the code (that little optimization with `b()` function must be present, as well as the "correct" function names).

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand the Playground's instruction counter. It does not complain about instruction count for this:

```
func bounce() {
  moveForward()
  collectGem()
  moveForward()
  toggleSwitch()
  moveForward()
  moveForward()
}

func btl() {
  bounce()
  turnLeft()
}

func b() {
  btl()
  btl()
}

b()
b()
```

Perhaps in the Playground, function-call overhead is negative. Stop unrolling those loops!

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if recursion will work. You said that extra moves are allowed, so I'm assuming that when you complete everything, it will automatically stop. Thus, something like this could work (assuming it lets you do this):

```
func name() {
    moveForward()
    collectGem()
    moveForward()
    toggleSwitch()
    moveForward()
    moveForward()
    turnLeft()

    name() //recursive call
}

name()
```

This deletes two lines of code! Which puts you under ten :D

Comment: Recursion is permitted. But it doesn't work... because it toggles the switches again (and it never ends).

Comment: @Cœur Ah well, then my assumption was wrong. However, I'm not really sure how else you're supposed to do it. It might be a flaw with the question.

Comment: Can you use if statements? If so, can you query whether the gem is in place or the switch was toggled? If so, move both the remaining calls along with the recursion call into the if statement and you have 10 statements. (Note, I don't know if this will work - it also may be an infinite recursion loop!)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that still only gets down to 11, but may give clue to a way forward:

```
func twomoves(){
    moveForward()
    collectGem()
    moveForward()
    toggleSwitch()
}

func grabngo(){
    twomoves()
    twomoves()
    turnLeft()
}

grabngo()
grabngo()
grabngo()
grabngo()
```

But since the playground allows the entry of a loop, why is that cheating?

Comment: Because using [advanced tricks](https://github.com/magwo/elevatorsaga/wiki/Haxor_matrix_frustrated) kills the essence of a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

So this gives you:

Amazing!
What a suprise! You used a loop to solve this puzzle. You've become a coding wizard! Next Page

```
func gfs() { 
  moveForward()
  collectGem()
  moveForward()
  toggleSwitch()
  moveForward()
  moveForward()
  turnLeft()
}
for _ 1...4 {
  gfs()
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was in a link in my question already, but you're not supposed to know about syntactic loops at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I too had 11 lines and was growing furious. Turns out it didn't like the name I had assigned (which funny enough was GrabNgo).
I changed it to "d" and then ran my d() four times and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This answer made Playground happy:

```
func gemSwitch() {
  moveForward()
  collectGem()
  moveForward()
  toggleSwitch()
  moveForward()
}

func forwTurn() {
  moveForward()
  turnLeft()
}

gemSwitch()
turnLeft()
gemSwitch()
forwTurn()
gemSwitch()
turnLeft()
gemSwitch()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func collectStoneAndTogleSwitch() {
    if stepCount == 1 || stepCount == 3 {
       moveForward()
       collectGem()
       moveForward()
       toggleSwitch()
       moveForward()
       turnLeft()   
    } else {
        moveForward()
        collectGem()
        moveForward()
        toggleSwitch()
        moveForward()
        moveForward()
        turnLeft()        
    }
}

var stepCount = 0

for i in 1 ... 4 {
    stepCount = stepCount + 1
    collectStoneAndTogleSwitch()
}
```

Comment: from the question: "note that I already figured out that using loops is cheating"